# How To See Which Ports Are Open On A Particular Firewall

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

Using the terminal I was wondering if it would be possible to see a list of all the active firewalls on a particular system that I have shelled into. I want to be able to see which ports are active pertaining to each firewall, so that I can change the restrictions.

Comment: What OS?  What do you mean by "systems using firewalls"?  A Firewall typically *blocks* traffic, with holes poked through it to allow access for a limited set of ports.  Is that what you're asking?  What ports are opened in the firewall?

Comment: Linux, as in which servers are using which firewalls. I wouldn't mind knowing which ports are opened either.

Comment: What would you do with that information?

Comment: Please, think again about it and write your question when you are sure what you want. Your question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could scan your localhost for open ports using a tool like [nmap](http://nmap.org/).

```
nmap -v -sT localhost
```

nmap can be built from source or installed from the repo of most (if not all) major distros.

Answer (score 2):

A server doesn't *use* a firewall.  You set up a firewall to block or allow ports.  that's it.  If you want to look at your firewall settings, try looking at the output of `iptables -L`.  (or `iptables -L -n` if you don't want it to resolve IPs).